# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

I am trying to evaluate limit $$\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}$$ The answer is $0$ but I am not able to get it.

My working:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} e^{\frac{ln(x+1)}{x+1}}$$
$$e^{\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} (\frac{ln(x+1)}{x+1})}$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} \frac{ln(x+1)}{x+1}$$

Using L'hopital rule:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} \frac{1}{x+1}$$

Substituting $-1^+$ into the equation

$$\frac{1}{-1+1} = \infty$$
$$\therefore e^\infty = \infty$$

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Answer should be zero...

Comment: In fact $\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1} =-\infty$  and $e^{-\infty} =0$

Comment: The big mistake you are doing is that you don't recognize that the expression doesn't lead to an indeterminate form and can be evaluated directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You correctly reduce to evaluating
$$
\lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}
$$
You ***cannot*** apply l'Hôpital here, because the hypotheses are not satisfied. This limit is $-\infty$, because the numerator has limit $-\infty$ and the denominator has limit $0$, but taking positive values.

So your limit is $e^{-\infty}=0$.

You *should* have realized that something went wrong: for $-1<x<0$, you have
$$
\ln(x+1)<0,\qquad x+1>0
$$
so the limit above can't be $\infty$, because the function only takes on negative values in a right neighborhood of $-1$.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This answer point out one important mistake but doen't mention at all what is the main mistake, that is do not recognize that the expression leads to $0^\infty$ which is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @user Sorry? There is no mistake in computing the limit of the logarithm, which I always find a good step in order to avoid remembering umpteen “rules”.

Comment: @egreg I'm not indeed asserting it is an error. I'm asserting that the big first mistake done was do not recognize that the orginal expression in not an indeterminate form. This is a big mistake. We should recongnize that foundamental fact and conclude directly without any other unnecessary manipulation.

Comment: @user I beg to disagree. Exponential limits are bad beasts and reducing them to simpler forms is a good way to manage them. No mistake at all: instead of remembering that $0^\infty=0$, but $0^{-\infty}=\infty$, you can just manage products or quotients.

Comment: @egreg That's fine have different points of view. From my side I think that recognize the indeterminate forms is a necessary basic prerequisite to face with the resolution of limits properly. it is just a suggestion for the asker and readers without any complaint  to your nice answer.

Comment: @user - egreg's answer does point out that the problem was the failure to recognize it is not an indeterminate form. That is why l'Hôpital's rule does not apply. The crucial thing is to recognize the lack before applying the theorem that requires it. Egreg points it out exactly where it is required. The only advantage to recognizing it earlier is to avoid a small bit of wasted effort.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes of course. My point is that when we need to solve a limit the first step must always be plug in the value and see what happens, when we don't face an indeterminate form the limit is solved. That's a methodological issue which I think should be pointed out as first observation. Then we can make secondary observations on other issues. As an analogy,when we study the convergence for a series $\sum a_n $ the first step is always to check if $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: @user Really? There's no need to check the limit, unless you *suspect* that the series is not convergent for that very reason.

Comment: @egreg I'm not trying to convince you. You seem sufficiently expert to me. :)

Answer (score 3):

In

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}$$

the numerator tends to $-\infty$ and the denominator to $0^+$, so you are not in the conditions of applicability of L'Hospital.

---

(But that limit is $-\infty$ and the initial one is $0$.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the limit can be evaluated directly, as should be always done as first attempt, indeed

$$x+1 \to 0^+\implies \frac1{x+1}\to \infty$$

and $0^\infty$ **is not an indeterminate form** therefore

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+} (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x+1}}=0^\infty=0$$

As an alternative, to avoid confusion, let $y=x+1$ with $y\to 0^+$ and conclude in the same way.

Comment: -1+ and 0+ are the same?

Comment: In this case since $x\to -1^+$ we mean $x=-1+\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<1$ therefore $y=x+1=\epsilon >0$.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, I see it now

Comment: @CuriousPerson Well done! Recall that always it is the first step to do with limits. Plug in the values and see if it leads to an indeterminate form.

Comment: I'll take note of that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the flaw in your approach is that $\ln(x+1)/(x+1)$ is of the form $-\infty/0$, not $0/0$, as $x\to-1^+$, so L'Hopital does not apply.  In problems like this, it sometimes helps to replace the one-sided limit at a finite value with a limit going to infinity. That is, think of $x$ tending to $-1$ from the right as $x=-1+1/u$ with $u\to\infty$.  Then $x+1=1/u$, so we have

$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1\over u\right)^u=\lim_{u\to\infty}{1\over u^u}=0$$